# Web scraping pagination with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying web scraping with scrapy. But I got "duplicates" warning. Can't jump next page.

How can I scrape all pages with pagination?

example site: teknosa.com

scraping url: https://www.teknosa.com/bilgisayar-tablet-c-116

pagination structure: `?s=%3Arelevance&page=0` (1,2,3,4,5, and more..)

My pagination code:

```
    next_page = soup.find('button', {'title': 'Daha Fazla Ürün Gör'})['data-gotohref']
    if next_page is not None:
        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the pagination in start_urls and increase or decrease range of page numbers.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class CarsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'car'
    start_urls=['https://www.teknosa.com/bilgisayar-tablet-c-116?s=%3Arelevance&page='+str(x)+'' for x in range(1,11)]
        
    def parse(self, response):
       print(response.url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process =CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl()
    process.start()
```

**Output:**

```
https://www.teknosa.com/bilgisayar-tablet-c-116?s=%3Arelevance&page=1
2022-05-01 08:55:06 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.teknosa.com/bilgisayar-tablet-c-116?s=%3Arelevance&page=2> (referer: None)
https://www.teknosa.com/bilgisayar-tablet-c-116?s=%3Arelevance&page=2
2022-05-01 08:55:06 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.teknosa.com/bilgisayar-tablet-c-116?s=%3Arelevance&page=5> (referer: None)
https://www.teknosa.com/bilgisayar-tablet-c-116?s=%3Arelevance&page=5
2022-05-01 08:55:06 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.teknosa.com/bilgisayar-tablet-c-116?s=%3Arelevance&page=6> (referer: None)
https://www.teknosa.com/bilgisayar-tablet-c-116?s=%3Arelevance&page=6
2022-05-01 08:55:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.teknosa.com/bilgisayar-tablet-c-116?s=%3Arelevance&page=7> (referer: None)
https://www.teknosa.com/bilgisayar-tablet-c-116?s=%3Arelevance&page=7
2022-05-01 08:55:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.teknosa.com/bilgisayar-tablet-c-116?s=%3Arelevance&page=3> (referer: None)
https://www.teknosa.com/bilgisayar-tablet-c-116?s=%3Arelevance&page=3
2022-05-01 08:55:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.teknosa.com/bilgisayar-tablet-c-116?s=%3Arelevance&page=4> (referer: None)
https://www.teknosa.com/bilgisayar-tablet-c-116?s=%3Arelevance&page=4
2022-05-01 08:55:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.teknosa.com/bilgisayar-tablet-c-116?s=%3Arelevance&page=8> (referer: None)
https://www.teknosa.com/bilgisayar-tablet-c-116?s=%3Arelevance&page=8
2022-05-01 08:55:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.teknosa.com/bilgisayar-tablet-c-116?s=%3Arelevance&page=9> (referer: None)
https://www.teknosa.com/bilgisayar-tablet-c-116?s=%3Arelevance&page=9
2022-05-01 08:55:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.teknosa.com/bilgisayar-tablet-c-116?s=%3Arelevance&page=10> (referer: None)
https://www.teknosa.com/bilgisayar-tablet-c-116?s=%3Arelevance&page=10
```

Multiple urls, pagination using for loop

```
import scrapy

class CarsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'car'
    
    def start_requests(self):
        urls=['url_1', 'url_2', 'url_3', ...]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url,callback=self.parse)
           
    def parse(self, response):
        ...
```